# React Hook Form move items between useFieldArray lists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm using React Hook Form to build a basic page builder application and it's been brilliant so far, I've been using the useFieldArray hook to create lists that contain items, however, I haven't found a way to move items between lists.

I know I can use the move() function to reorder items within the same list, however, since each list has its own nested useFieldArray I can't move the item from one list component to another list component.

If anyone knows of a way around this it would be much appreciated!

Here is a very simplified example of my current setup:

```
export const App = () => {
    const methods = useForm({
        defaultValues: {
            lists: [
                {
                    list_id: 1,
                    items: [
                        {
                            item_id: 1,
                            name: 'Apple'   
                        },
                        {
                            item_id: 2,
                            name: 'Orange'    
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    list_id: 2,
                    items: [
                        {
                            item_id: 3,
                            name: 'Banana'   
                        },
                        {
                            item_id: 4,
                            name: 'Lemon'   
                        }
                    ]
                }             
            ]    
        }
    });
    return (
        <FormProvider {...methods}>
            <Page/>
        </FormProvider>
    )
}
```

```
export const Page = () => {
    const { control } = useFormContext();
    const { fields } = useFieldArray({
        control,
        name: 'lists'
    })

    return (
        <ul>
            {fields?.map((field, index) => (
                <List listIdx={index} />
            ))}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

```
export const List = ({ listIdx }) => {
    const { control, watch } = useFormContext();
    const { fields, move } = useFieldArray({
        control,
        name: `lists[${sectionIdx}].items`
    })

    const handleMove = (prevIdx, nextIdx) => {
        // this allows me to move within lists but not between them
        move(prevIdx, nextIdx);
    }

    return (
        <li>
            <p>ID: {watch(lists[${listIdx}].list_id)}</p>
            <ul>
                {fields?.map((field, index) => (
                    <Item listIdx={index} itemIdx={index} handleMove={handleMove}/>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </li>
    )
}
```

```
export const Item = ({ listIdx, itemIdx, handleMove }) => {
    const { control, register } = useFormContext();

    return (
        <li>
            <p>ID: {watch(lists[${listIdx}].items[${itemIdx}].item_id)}</p>
            <label
                Name:
                <input { ...register('lists[${listIdx}].items[${itemIdx}]) }/>
            />
            <button onClick={() => handleMove(itemIdx, itemIdx - 1)}>Up</button>
            <button onClick={() => handleMove(itemIdx, itemIdx + 1)}>Down</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you'd not like to alter your default values (your data structure), I think the best way to handle this is using `update` method returning from `useFieldArray`. You have the data of both inputs that are going to be moved around, knowing their list index and item index, you could easily update their current positions with each other's data.

Comment: I thought about this, but how would you access the list components useFieldArray update method from another list component?

Comment: You also call 'useFieldArray' for the 'lists' in Page component. Use the 'update' method from that hook.